# Express $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ given $g$ is symmetric to $f$ with respect to $x_0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to:

> Express $g(x)$ in terms of $f(x)$ given $g$ is symmetric to $f$ with respect to $x_0$
>   analytically.

I've shown this graphically, but didn't manage to do that symbolically. Consider the image: [image: x^2]

I've chosen $f(x) = (x-1)^2$ as an example and $x_0 = 1$. Then we may take a look at $2x_0$ and see that for any $f$ and $g$ the fact that $f(x) = g(2x_0-x)$ holds in case $f$ and $g$ are symmetric with respect to some $x_0$. But how do i show that analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

We know that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ and since $g$ is symmetric to $f$ at $x_0$, for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $$f(x_0+x)=g(x_0-x)$$ But the sign between $x_0$ and $x$ depends on whether $g$ is to the left/right of $f$.